# Is it possible to remove a scoreboard score by a scoreboard score?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The question I'm asking might be confusing but I'll give an example:

```
/scoreboard players remove @p score score
```

So it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

`remove`, `add`, and `set` will only accept constants. To take away one score from another, use `operation`.

For example, the following will reduce the closest player's `score1` by their `score2`:

```
/scoreboard players operation @p score1 -= @p score2
```

The syntax is:

```
/scoreboard players operation <targetName> <targetObjective> <operation> <selector> <objective>
```

The available `operation`s are, from [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Command_reference):

- `+=` Addition: add selector's score to targetName's
- `-=` Subtraction: subtract selector's score from targetName's
- `*=` Multiplication: set targetName's score to the product of targetName and selector's scores
- `/=` Integer Division: set targetName's score to itself divided by selector's score
- `%=` Modular Division: set targetName's score to the remainder of the division between itself and selector's score
- `=` Assign: set targetName's score to selector's score
- `<` Min: if selector's score is less than targetName's score, then set targetName's score to selector's score
- `>` Max: if selector's score is greater than targetName's score, then set targetName's score to selector's score
- `><` Swaps the scores of selector with targetName

All but `><` (swapping) will only affect the `targetName`'s `targetObjective`. `selector`'s `objective` will be left as it is.